# OneDrive for Azure web site deployment

Tags: azure, onedrive, azure-web-app-service

I have a file to large for `Git`, and my `Dropbox` storage dropped, so it now full.

Can `OneDrive` for Business be used like a `DropBox` for deploying web sites?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't upload the large file to a blob and have your website access it directly from that location (vs deploying it to the website itself)?

Comment: Lazy sync, desire to use onedrive since we have a bunch of space

Comment: Vote here: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/7105109-deploy-from-onedrive-to-azure-websites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is **NO**, currently we have only below options for source control that are supported by `Azure`:

- Visual Studio Online
- GitHub
- Bitbucket
- Local Git
- Dropbox
- CodePlex
- List item
- Mercurial repository

Comment: There will be soon: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/commits/613199dc205f427e72a20bf43a49543c105716fc/Kudu.Services/ServiceHookHandlers/OneDriveHandler.cs

Answer (score 4):

OneDrive is now supported.  It creates a Apps > Azure Web Apps > YourSiteName folder in your OneDrive root.

Then just drop your web files in that folder, and then hit the Synch button in the azure portal and it will pull the files from the folder.

I just deployed a node.js app from my OneDrive.

Answer (score 3):

As of October 2016 onedrive has been added to the deployment option source on azure. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Continuous development allows this origins:

- Visual Studio Online
- OneDrive
- Local Git Repository
- Github
- Bitbucket
- Dropbox
- External Repository

In the case of OneDrive, you only have to log in using the credentials of the OneDrive account from where you want to deploy the website from, and then select the folder.

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive doesn't work for CD as you have to manually sync in the portal :( I've not tried DropBox.

It's seems VC is the only workable solution which is not ideal as you have to check in built artifacts - that's an anti pattern